# export vs export_ok in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I can not understand what is the difference/use case of `EXPORT_OK` vs `EXPORT`.
Most resources mentions something in the lines of:

> @Export allows to export the functions and variables of modules to
>   user’s namespace using the standard import method. This way, we don’t
>   need to create the objects for the modules to access its members.
>   @EXPORT_OK does export of symbols on demand basis for selective list
>   of symbols (subroutines and variables) of the module.

But I really don't see the difference/meaning here.
Can someone please provide a small fundamental example of the difference/usage of these 2 symbols?

Comment: You shouldn't export many symbols by default if any at all. @EXPORT will typically be small or empty. @EXPORT_OK can include far more. For example, Encode exports `encode` and `decode` by default (`@EXPORT`), but not `is_utf8` (`@EXPORT_OK`)

Answer (score 46):

Let's say I have a package `MyPackage` that uses `@EXPORT`.

```
#this is MyPackage.pm
package MyPackage;
@EXPORT = qw(do_awesome_thing);

sub do_awesome_thing { ... }

sub be_awesome { ... }
```

Now, when I use `MyPackage` in my code,

```
#this is myscript.pl
use MyPackage;

do_awesome_thing(); #works

be_awesome(); #doesn't work
MyPackage::be_awesome(); #works
```

`do_awesome_thing` gets automatically exported to my code from `MyPackage`, without me having to say "give this to me". `be_awesome` isn't exported (and it won't be exported with `@EXPORT_OK` either, I'm just showing that part to get you clear on what "exporting" gives us).

On the other hand, if I have a package `MyOtherPackage` that uses `@EXPORT_OK`,

```
#this is MyOtherPackage.pm
package MyOtherPackage;
@EXPORT_OK = qw(do_awesome_thing);

sub do_awesome_thing { ... }

sub be_awesome { ... }
```

and then try

```
#this is mynewscript.pl
use MyOtherPackage;

do_awesome_thing(); #doesn't work
MyOtherPackage::do_awesome_thing(); #works, as always
```

the line calling `do_awesome_thing` directly won't work. This is because putting something in `@EXPORT_OK` says "give this to my users only if they ask for it". Since we've just said `use MyOtherPackage` without explicitly asking for `do_awesome_thing` to be imported here, it doesn't get imported, and is accessible only by specifying the package name.

The way you ask for `do_awesome_thing` to be imported is to say `use MyOtherPackage qw(do_awesome_thing)` in the second line of `mynewscript.pl` above. This says import that module and make `do_awesome_thing` available directly. After that, the fourth line in `mynewscript.pl` above will start working.

Note that the user can specify `use MyPackage qw(do_awesome_thing)` with the first package also, and in that case, anything else in the `@EXPORT` list won't be exported, only `do_awesome_thing` will be. So, except for the default case of `use PackageName;`, `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK` behave similarly. In the default case, anything in `@EXPORT` gets thrown into the user's script automatically, while `@EXPORT_OK` is more polite and doesn't export anything.

Comment: *With @EXPORT, you only have two choices*... wrong; just wrong. `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK` work mostly the same: in either case the user can specify the list of names they wish to import. They *only* differ in what happens when the user provides *no list of names to import* - in that situation, things on `@EXPORT` are exported, and things on `@EXPORT_OK` are not.

Comment: @tobyink Thanks, haven't worked with EXPORT much so didn't know that, I've  changed that part now. While Googling to confirm this I came across this O'Reilly book (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/advprog/ch06_05.htm) which seems to make the same mistake I did: "If the module uses EXPORT instead of EXPORT_OK , the user gets all the exported symbols, regardless of whether they were mentioned in the import list or not." 
But I've tested the behaviour and confirmed that you were right and the book (apparently) wrong.

Answer (score 17):

From the [fine Exporter manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#How-to-Import):

> - `use YourModule;`
>     This imports all the symbols from YourModule's `@EXPORT` into the namespace of the *use* statement.
> - `use YourModule ();`
>     This causes perl to load your module but does not import any symbols.
> - `use YourModule qw(...);`
>     This imports only the symbols listed by the caller into their namespace. All listed symbols must be in your `@EXPORT` or `@EXPORT_OK`, else an error occurs. The advanced export features of Exporter are accessed like this, but with list entries that are syntactically distinct from symbol names.

So, if you use `@EXPORT` and someone does the usual `use YourModule;`, then you've just polluted their namespace with everything in `@EXPORT`. But, if you use `@EXPORT_OK`, they have to specifically ask for things to be imported so the person using your module has control over what happens to their namespace.

The difference is really a matter of who controls what gets into the `use`r's namespace: if you use `@EXPORT` then the module being `use`d does, if you use `@EXPORT_OK` then the code doing the import controls their own namespace.

Of course, you could always say `use Whatever();` to keep impolite modules from polluting your namespace but that's ugly and you shouldn't have to kludge around rude code that wants to scribble all over your namespace.

Comment: So `use YourModule qw(a b);` and `@EXPORT qw(a b);` is meaningless? If not then I still don't see why we need `@EXPORT_OK`

Comment: @Jim `our @EXPORT` holds the symbols you export by default (that is, with `use YourModule;`). Doing this is considered a *bad practice*. The `@EXPORT_OK` holds a list of all symbols that *can* be exported upon explicit request.