# Why does a function name have to be specified in a use statement?

Tags: function, perl, perl-module

In `perl`, sometimes it is necessary to specify the function name in the `use` statement.

For example:

```
use Data::DPath ('dpath');
```

will work but

```
use Data::DPath;
```

won't.

Other modules don't need the function names specified, for example:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
```

Why?

Comment: Do you have a specific `WWW::Mechanize` example where a function is used without including it by name? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @ray `use WWW::Mechanize; my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize; $mech->get("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: `$mech->get(...)` is simply an object calling an instance method, so it's not really the same thing.

Comment: @CJ7, because `WWW::Mechanize->new` was called, created a `WWW::Mechanize` object and methods were called from there. Some modules *will* export a bunch of functions into main, but that's consider impolite these days. If you need a function from a module, *ask* for it.

Comment: @ray I have my own `Funcs.pm` file with functions in it.  In order to import the functions all I have to do is `use Funcs;`.

Comment: @CJ7 Did you define the `@EXPORT_OK` array?

Comment: @CJ7: Please update your OP to include an MCVE, as I asked a few minutes ago.

Comment: @ray: You're giving bad advice. An MCVE isn't really relevant to this question, and the issue of the OP's own `Funcs` module needs to be a separate question if the want to ask about it.

Comment: @Borodin, I'm not so sure I am, especially given his apparent confusion between an actual function, an object with methods, and his comment that he has a `Funcs.pm` module where he gets to import and use all the content without defining `EXPORT`/`EXPORT_OK` in it. Something's amiss and it would've helped to see what code he was using that actually led him to his question. I don't think it needs to be a separate question, since it's relevant to clarifying his situation.

Answer (score 9):

Each module chooses what functions it exports by default. Some choose to export *no* functions by default at all, you have to ask for them. There's a few good reasons to do this, and one bad one.

If you're a class like [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize), then you don't need to export any functions. Everything is a class or object method. `my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new`.

If you're a pragma like [strict](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) then there are no functions nor methods, it does its work simply by being loaded.

Some modules export waaay too many functions by default. An example is [Test::Deep](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep#EXPORTS) which exports...

> all any array array_each arrayelementsonly arraylength arraylengthonly bag blessed bool cmp_bag cmp_deeply cmp_methods cmp_set code eq_deeply hash
>   hash_each hashkeys hashkeysonly ignore Isa isa listmethods methods noclass
>   none noneof num obj_isa re reftype regexpmatches regexponly regexpref
>   regexprefonly scalarrefonly scalref set shallow str subbagof subhashof
>   subsetof superbagof superhashof supersetof useclass

The problem comes when another module tries to export the same functions, or if you write a function with the same name. Then they clash and you get mysterious warnings.

```
$ cat ~/tmp/test.plx
use Test::Deep;
use List::Util qw(all);

$ perl -w ~/tmp/test.plx
Subroutine main::all redefined at /Users/schwern/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.2/lib/5.20.2/Exporter.pm line 66.
 at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx line 2.
Prototype mismatch: sub main::all: none vs (&@) at /Users/schwern/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.2/lib/5.20.2/Exporter.pm line 66.
 at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx line 2.
```

For this reason, exporting lots of functions is discouraged. For example, [the Exporter documentation advises](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.1/Exporter.html#Selecting-What-To-Export)...

> Do not export method names!
>
> Do not export anything else by default without a good reason!
>
> Exports pollute the namespace of the module user. If you must export try to use @EXPORT_OK in preference to @EXPORT and avoid short or common symbol names to reduce the risk of name clashes.

Unfortunately, some modules take this too far. [Data::DPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::DPath) is a good example. It has a really clear main function, dpath(), which it should export by default. Otherwise it's basically useless.

You can always turn off exporting with `use Some::Module ();`.

Comment: I have my own `Funcs.pm` file with functions in it. In order to import the functions all I have to do is `use Funcs;`  The `Funcs.pm` file simply contains the functions and there is no mention anywhere of `@EXPORT_OK`.

Comment: @CJ7 I think you didn't put a package name in Funcs.pm, so it's all going into `main`, the default package. This is very impolite. It is a very strong convention that Funcs.pm will use the Funcs package and not pollute other packages without a very good reason

Comment: @CJ7: Presumably, you don't have the package notations in your file, so the whole thing is automatically available in the global namespace.  You can do that — it works.  But formal modules (such as `WWW::Mechanize`) use the package notations to avoid exposing their internals, and the well-disciplined modules only export the minimum of necessary names, or the user-specified list of names.  It avoids unnecessary pollution of the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that some modules simply contain functions in them and they may or may not have chosen to export them by default, and that means they may need to be explicitly imported by the script to access directly or use a fully qualified name to access them. For example:

```
# in some script
use SomeModule;
# ...
SomeModule::some_function(...);
```

or

```
use SomeModule ('some_function');
# ...
some_function(...);
```

This can be the case if the module was not intended to be used in an object-oriented way, i.e. where no classes have been defined and lines such as `my $obj = SomeModule->new()` wouldn't work.

If the module has defined content in the `EXPORT_OK` array, it means that the client code will only get access to it if it "asks for it", rather than "automatically" when it's actually present in the `EXPORT` array.

Some modules automatically export their content by means of the `@EXPORT` array. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912400/export-vs-export-ok-in-perl) and the [`Exporter` docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) have more detail on this.

Without you actually posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's difficult to know what you've done in your `Funcs.pm` module that may be allowing you to import everything without using `EXPORT` and `EXPORT_OK` arrays. Perhaps you did not include the `package Funcs;` line in your module, as @JonathanLeffler suggested in the comments. Perhaps you did something else. Perl is one of those languages where people pride themselves in the [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TMTOWTDI) mantra, often to a detrimental/counter-productive level, IMHO.

The 2nd example you presented is very different and fairly straightforward. When you have something like:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
$mech->get("http://www.google.com");
```

you're simply instantiating an object of type `WWW::Mechanize` and calling an instance method, called `get`, on it. There's no need to import an object's methods because the methods are *part of the object itself*. Modules looking to have an OOP approach are not meant to export anything. They're different situations.